# Find file by exact name in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I need to find all files that are called exactly `wc-search.xml`.

When I make the "normal" search, I find a lot of unuseful files

[image]

There is no mode to specify regular expressions, only file filters that doesn't help. How can I resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find only an useful workaround: search with `Find in Files`, and insert the file name in `File mask`, leaving empty the search bar

[image]

Comment: 2024 update: I'm also not seeing any other option, are we missing something?